# Topology of a 3D wired Mandala?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, circles, symmetric-groups

There is a so called 3D-wired Mandala, based upon $2$ large circles each flowered symmetrically on its circumference by two sets of each $8$ half-circles. The circles are interconnected together by one of the sets of each.

The Mandala, continuousely transforming, can take remarkablly different symmetric structures; in the simplest case overlapping flat rosettes. All strutures, however, remain belonging to the same Mandala.

The structure is difficult to describe but I found a video that demonstrates the structure [>>> here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS7XLTcKTxY)

I am searching for whether there exists a mathematical approach that would capture the topolgy of this specific Mandala and particularly *the set of shapes/forms that it can possess (possible group characteristics)*.

May you have prpositions in this respect or research references, on which I could elaborate further?

Comment: Perhaps only tangentially related would be the idea of a 'configuration space of linkages' which is a topological space where the points are configurations of some hinged rigid structure in some ambient space - normally $\mathbb{R}^n$. As far as I'm aware, it's an active area of research; especially in engineering and robotics, as well as algebraic topology.

Comment: The chapter 8 of [Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-8-fractals/) talks about fractals, and can give hints on how this geometry can be drawn.